# How to define a controller which will be visible all time Angularsjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, autocomplete

I have a route defined in this way in Angularjs:

```
mainApp.config(['$routeProvider',
  function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.
      when('/test', {
        templateUrl: 'templates/test.html',
        controller:'testController'
      }).
      otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/'
      });
}]);
```

And Now I have an autocomplete function(input) which must be visible to all pages:

```
mainApp.controller('autocompleteController',function($scope,dataFactory){
    dataFactory.get('test.json').then(function(data){
        $scope.items=data;
    });
    $scope.name="";
    $scope.onItemSelected=function(){
        console.log('selected='+$scope.name);
    }
});

.....
```

The autocomplete controller has its own template and when I include it in the index.html it doesn't work(doesn't show suggestions),but when I use it alone with just one controller it works.My question is to find a way to include it in any pages displayed(in any controller called).
Thanks to the reply!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's relatively simple, you just keep the html for it outside of `ng-view` and make sure the container has `ng-controller="autocompleteController"`

The routeProvider only affects what is inside `ng-view`

Comment: This must work this is what I tried :<div ng-view></div><div ng-controller="autocompleteController">Content of autocomplete  </div>???